# AsyncTask not working when fetching data from server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-json

I am working on a project.. when i have run my project in 2.2 version avd its work fine in my way.... but when i used AsyncTask in my code and run on 4.0 version avd its not work properly... i have found following errors in my logcat

1. Error parsing data java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2. Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for customer
   can i implement properly the AsyncTask in my code? 
   please check my code ... what's going to wrong is this....

   ```
            public class Login extends Activity {
    String success, cus_id, cus_name;
         SessionManager session;

        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.login);

   Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           com.amplio.MyCustomEditText et = (com.amplio.MyCustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.etmob);
           String mobileno = et.getText().toString();
           if (mobileno.length() > 0) {
               final ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_mob",
                       mobileno));

               Thread thread = new Thread() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       try {
                           String response = null;
                           response = LoginHttpClient
                                   .executeHttpPost(
                                           "http://10.0.2.2/android/mobile_no.php",
                                           postParameters);
                           System.out.println(response);
                           JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                           JSONArray jArray = json
                                   .getJSONArray("customer");
                           for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                               JSONObject json_data = jArray
                                       .getJSONObject(i);
                               success = json_data.getString("success");
                               cus_id = json_data.getString("cus_id");
                               cus_name = json_data.getString("cus_name");
                           }
                           if (success.equals("1")) {
                               session = new SessionManager(
                                       getApplicationContext());
                               session.createLoginSessionRemMe(cus_id,
                                       cus_name);
                               Intent iv = new Intent(
                                       getApplicationContext(),
                                       Verify.class);
                               startActivity(iv);
                           } else {
                               // not valid email id or pass
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                       "Incorrect Mobile No",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                       }
                   }
               };
               thread.start();

           }

           else {
               // display message if text fields are empty
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Mobile no is required",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   });
          }}
   ```

Comment: where is `AsyncTask`?. You also display toast in thread. wrong

Comment: @Raghunandan what i do...?

Comment: use asynctask and do your network operation in doInbackground and update ui in onpostexecute

Comment: @Raghunandan i am fetching data from server... when i simply used this code in avd 2.2 without thread it is work fine ....But when i used thread in code and run on avd 4.0 its not work

Comment: after 3.0 you can't do n/w opertion on the ui thread. Read the docs.

Comment: where is the asynctask involved in this you are creating a java thread for getting the data do you know the difference between a java thread and android asynctask thread

Comment: @Amardeep what exception do you get. post the stacktrace

Comment: sry i used thread in place of asynctask ....

Comment: @Raghunandan plz check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560303/asynctask-not-working-when-fetching-data-from-server